# How to ask the user to add new element in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a bot in Dialogflow.

Here is what I need:

```
customer: Hello 
bot: hello, what's your name? 
customer: John 
bot: Please enter the first element. 
customer: element1 
bot: Did you finish? 
customer: No 
bot: Please enter the second element. 
....
```

Please advise how can I implement it? I am trying to create an intent with action and prompt but  the agent doesn't ask me "Please enter the first element".

I also need to make first, second .. a counter that updates with each iteration / question.

Can you please advise where can I find a guideline how to achieve this kind task?

So far I have created an agent and playing with intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to write some code for fulfillment (using webhook or even inline editor), analyze incoming messages in your code and generate answer.

If you don't want to write any code, it should be also possible to achieve this using Dialogflow's context to store some information and followup intents to continue asking for elements. But in case you would like to ask user for multiple elements - it could be hard to maintain in Dialogflow. I have created and tested sample bot this way with following intents:

[image]

Please note that I have removed default Welcome intent to not interfere with custom "hello" intent.

Comment: But if I have 500 elements? I want it to be automated where Nth element will be a variable: first, second, hundredth, .... like a series.

Comment: In this case I think it would be much easier to go with fulfillment and write some code.

Comment: Can you please advise how to do this? Can you provide one - two examples?

Comment: First of all I would recommend going through [documentation for fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview), next you will have pick a language in which you would write your fulfillment. Sorry that I won't give you specific answer or example, but I think you should try some simple examples at first, check how fulfillment work and later adapt them to your problem. You can find multiple examples in [Dialogflow GitHub reposisotory](https://github.com/dialogflow).